# Is there a tool or a way to speedtest java classess/methods per line of code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, optimization

At work i often work with Spring Boot Backends. Every now and then i need to optimize methods to run faster, so that the user dont have to wait and the request doesn't time out.

After watching this video: https://youtu.be/oewDaISQpw0?t=566 . I really liked the idea of having execution time shown per line of code, rather than of the full method. I began searching for similar tools for Java, but found nothing.

So i began thinking of a own solution.

I created a class that takes a .java file and edits it in a way, that there is a time print after every line, compiles it and loads it into the code to execute it. Before execution i redirect the System.out stream to catch the time prints. This kinda works, but only for standalone classes with no dependencys, with does not really work for me with my Sring service depending on other services and repositories. So i thought about replacing the class at runtime with my edited class, which does not really work in java(?). I also tried to use a InvocationHandler to catch the method calls of my service and route them to my edited class, but i still would need the dependencys and apparently the method proxy does only really work for interfaces.

My goal would be to have method and class annotation, that would mark the classes/methods to be speedtested. When called their times would be recorded and served on an exposed endpoint as a formatted .html.

Im kinda out of ideas right now and could need some help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Printing the timing on each lines sounds like a bad idea to measure run times, because printing to console/file takes more time than the actual line (in general). This would influence the measurement by a certain margin.

Comment: i reset the timer after every print, so that would not really be a problem i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a Profiler. Most can tell you execution time per method, and memory usage, identified as 'hotspots' - where either the majority of time is spent, or most memory consumed.

Netbeans has a built in Profiler feature:
https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-intro.html

Also, take a look at VisualVM:
https://visualvm.github.io/download.html

There's other commercial products available too if you search for 'Java profiler'

Comment: does it also profile the execution time of library methods? that would be almost perfect then.

Comment: If your method A calls library method B then the execution time of your method A will include the time spent executing all of your code and any other code it calls whether that is your code or library code. Typically the tool will give you a method by method breakdown though, regardless of whether it's your code or code from a library. At the end of the day it's all Java code whether you wrote it or not (the tool doesn't know the difference)

Comment: this is acceptable! thanks a lot!